# Importing .csv into iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv

Referencing this [Importing csv into iOS app by email attachment](https://spritebandits.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/importing-csv-data-file-into-an-ios-app-via-email-attachment/).

In this line:

> Note.The code above works fine for iOS 3.2 +. If your app supports newer systems iOS 4.0+ only you may use self.window.rootViewController instead of self.viewController here.

I've tried using `self.window.rootViewController` and it references my first view controller. However, I need to import the data in the .csv file into my third view controller.

I'm wondering if it is possible to use a segue identifier to transfer the `NSURL` from the first view controller to the the third view controller or is there an easier way to do it directly from the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate.m`?

---

Edit:

The `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
    [self.window.rootViewController handleOpenURL:url];
}

return YES;
}
```

Error I'm getting:

> No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector
>   'handleOpenURL:'

My mistake, it is the 2nd view controller after a segue from the root view controller.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what your AppDelegate's `application:handleOpenURL:` method currently looks like?  When you say "third view controller", what do you mean by that?  The third view controller in a tab view controller or the third view controller after two segues from your root view controller?

Comment: Use singleton to store the data loaded in 1st VC. Then that data is available everywhere.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I've edit my question and my mistake, it is the second view controller after one segue from my root view controller

Comment: so if your app is launched with a URL, you want to skip the first view controller completely?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I intended for it to be.

Comment: I've thought of a couple solutions here & they all feel tricky or janky, because not only do you need to care about doing an instant segue from the root view controller when a URL launches your app, but what happens if you are already deep in your app (after a few segues or on different screens that don't have a direct segue back to that second view controller) and a URL comes in for you to open. If this were my app, I'd display the URL in the root view controller. If your first controller is a login screen, then after logging in, make your second view controller the new root view controller.

Comment: Just to be clear, is root view controller the initial view controller or the view controller that the user is currently looking at? Yeah, my first controller is a menu screen and following your advice, I should change the root view controller to the second controller?